# Creating a new cipher!

Tags: algorithm-design, encryption

http://flashbackcipher.blogspot.ae/2015/03/introducing-flashback.html

Hey guys the above is the blog for a new cipher, if you guys can take a look and suggest problems.. it would be of great help!! :D Thanks ! If this cipher is good I can start developing a C++ code that would utilize this cipher! :)

Comment: This is a questions and answers site, not a site to review designs. If you want your system reviewed, submit it to a peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: What's wrong with existing proven ciphers? Why wasting time with something that is certainly bound to fail?

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

- It is going to be extremely easy to find $y$ as the GCD of every number of the ciphertext. The only way to avoid this is to make all the letters' associated numbers have a common factor, but then you can just divide out by said common factor (it'll mess with the successive letters, but we'll get to that later).
- Once you have a candidate value for $y$, check and see if it might be correct: divide out the whole ciphertext by $y$, square the first few letters, and see if those squares are in the rest of the ciphertext, which means that you have a second occurrence of the same letter ($(x^n)^2=(x^2)^n$). If you find this, you probably had the right value of $y$.
- You can also start by squaring the first few elements of the ciphertext: $(x^ny)^2=x^{2n}y^2=(x^2)^ny^2$. This means that if the first letter of the plaintext appeared later as well (encoded as $(x^2)^ny$, then it was encoded as a factor of the square of the first element of the ciphertext. So try dividing the squares of the first few ciphertext elements by all the other characters; this is fairly quick to do, and will get you more info about $y$ as well.
- If you have the value of $y$ down, you might finding factors of the numbers divided by $y$; this can be fast if small primes divide them (all you need is one prime factor). Once you have a prime factor, compute what power it was taken to (this is easy; start with $p$ that divides $C$, then check $p^2$, $p^4$, $p^8$, and so on (squaring each time and storing each one) until it doesn't divide $C$ anymore, then you can do binary search).

So, this scheme has some pretty major weaknesses. I would say it's fatally flawed, and is easily breakable. There might be some really, really specific letter->number mappings that make the simple attacks not work right, but I strongly suspect that even those are easy to break.